# Combination Problem -- forming a committee with two conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In a certain Rotary Club, there are $10$ female bankers, $15$ male bankers, $4$ female lawyers, and $10$ male lawyers. Find the numbers of ways that a committee of $7$ persons can be formed from all these members if the committee must have exactly $4$ lawyers and at the same time must have exactly $5$ men.

Comment: Seems fairly standard, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but the fact that there are two criteria kind of threw me off

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: You have anywhere from $0$ to $5$ male lawyers. Count how many ways you can form a committee for each possible number of male lawyers.

Comment: Hint:  go case by case.  How many ways are there if all the lawyers are men?  What if exactly $1$ is male?  and so on.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I can't seem to follow

Comment: Can I get a little more help?

Comment: So I am thinking that I would subtract the "bad" cases 14C1+14C2+14C3+14C5+14C6+14C7 (since we want 4 lawyers) and 25C1+25C2+25C3+25C4+25C6+25C7 (since we want 5 men) from the total number of unrestricted combinations 39C7. Is this correct?

Comment: Alright, you're trying something, which is a good first step. What you have written won't work though, because going through all of the $14 C k$ doesn't count possible committees, just possible ways of picking some number of lawyers not equal to $4$. Try this- how many ways are there of picking such a committee if you have no male lawyers, and you follow the given constraints?

Comment: "You have anywhere from 0 to 5 male lawyers." No, there are exactly 2 women on the committee, so there are 0,1,or 2 female lawyers, giving 4,3,or 2 male lawyers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... That seems to be very sexist comitee. Apart of that:

As we need exatcly 4 lawyers (3 bankers) and exactly 5 men (2 women), we have 3 cases:

1. All bankers are men
2. One banker is woman
3. Two bankers are women

If we parametrise these cases by the number of female bankers (denote it by $n$, then the commision will contain:

- $n$ female bankers (out of 10)
- $3-n$ male bankers (out of 15)
- $2-n$ female lawyers (out of 4)
- $4-(2-n)=2+n$ male lawyers (out of 7)

All these cases are distinct, therefore the answer is simply sum of all arrangements for these cases:

$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}\binom{10}{n}\binom{15}{3-n}\binom{4}{2-n}\binom{7}{2+n}\\
=57330+147000+141750 \\
=346080
$$